# jQuery hover situation

Tags: jquery, jquery-hover

So I have this bit of code, which creates a div to block an image of a checkmark and then slides right to make it look like the checkmark is being drawn. Everything works fine, except I want the code to execute as if the user stayed hovered for awhile even if the user only hovers for a split second. Currently, the  animation stops when the user stops hovering. Thanks folks!

```
$('li.activated').hover(function () {
    $('ul.actilist').prepend($('<div>&nbsp;</div>').addClass('slidebox'));
}, function () {
    $('ul.actilist').find('div.slidebox').remove();
});

$('li.activated').hover(function() {
    $('div.slidebox').animate({width: '-=17px', marginLeft: '+=14px'}, {duration: '800',easing: 'swing',queue: true});
}, function() {
    if( $('div.slidebox').width() < 17 ){
        $('div.slidebox').animate({width: '+=17px', marginLeft: '-=14px'}, {duration: '2000',easing: 'swing',queue: true});
    }
});
```

Comment: Why do you have two different `.hover()` method/instances both targeting the same `$('li.activated')`?

Comment: Can you post a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `setTimeout` function to delay the mouseleave event:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('div.slidebox').animate({width: '+=17px', marginLeft: '-=14px'}, {duration: '2000',easing: 'swing',queue: true});
}, 800);
```

That won't do quite what you want, though, because if the user moves the mouse out and hastily back in, the div will shrink further, then grow back to its intended size after the timeout expires.  (Doing this repeatedly can cause the div to briefly shrink to nothing.)  To prevent this, you need to prevent the hover events from triggering in case of this "canceled mouseleave".  That takes a bit more code:

```
var hovered = false;

$('li.activated').hover(function() {
    if(hovered) return;
    hovered = true;
    $('div.slidebox').animate({width: '-=17px', marginLeft: '+=14px'}, {duration: '800',easing: 'swing',queue: true});
}, function() {
    var element = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
        if($(element).is(':hover') || !hovered) return;
        hovered = false;
        $('div.slidebox').animate({width: '+=17px', marginLeft: '-=14px'}, {duration: '2000',easing: 'swing',queue: true});
    }, 800);
});​
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uUjhJ/2/

That mostly works, but with some diligent mouse-waving, it's possible to make the animation "crack" and start pumping like a bellows (until it goes through the animation queue).  This is started by moving the mouse back in while the mouseleave animation is playing, and the only way I've been able to find to fix it is to set the "queue" option to false and change the animation values to fixed values (rather than relative values using += and -=):

```
var hovered = false;

$('li.activated').hover(function() {
    if(hovered) return;
    hovered = true;
    $('div.slidebox').animate({width: '83px', marginLeft: '14px'}, {duration: '800',easing: 'swing',queue: false});
}, function() {
    var element = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
        if($(element).is(':hover') || !hovered) return;
        hovered = false;
        $('div.slidebox').animate({width: '100px', marginLeft: '0px'}, {duration: '2000',easing: 'swing',queue: false});
    }, 800);
});​
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uUjhJ/3/

In theory it should be possible to make the original method work properly by keeping careful track of state and using callbacks in the calls to `animate`, but it's quite finicky and I haven't been able to make it work.

EDIT: Ah, missed that you also wanted to add/delete the div in the hover event.  This does the job:

```
var hovered = false;

$('li.activated').hover(function() {
    if(hovered) return;
    hovered = true;
    if(!$('div.slidebox').length)
        $('ul.actilist').prepend($('<div>&nbsp;</div>').addClass('slidebox'));
    $('div.slidebox').animate({width: '83px', marginLeft: '14px'}, {duration: '800',easing: 'swing',queue: false});
}, function() {
    var element = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
        if($(element).is(':hover') || !hovered) return;
        hovered = false;
        $('div.slidebox').animate({width: '100px', marginLeft: '0px'}, {duration: '2000',easing: 'swing',queue: false,complete: function() {
            if($(element).is(':hover')) return;
            $('ul.actilist').find('div.slidebox').remove();
        }});
    }, 800);
});​
```

Note that the element is removed in the "complete" callback to ensure that it's removed after the animation rather than before, and both the adding code and the removing code double-check that they aren't conflicting with anything (double-adding or removing when it was re-shown).

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uUjhJ/4/

Answer (score -1):

I'm not too familiar with the `hover()` function, but that code should queue the animation (wasn't tested):

```
$('li.activated').mouseenter(function() {
    $('div.slidebox').animate({width: '-=17px', marginLeft: '+=14px'}, {duration: '800',easing: 'swing',queue: true});
}).mouseleave(function() {
    if( $('div.slidebox').width() < 17 ){
        $('div.slidebox').animate({width: '+=17px', marginLeft: '-=14px'}, {duration: '2000',easing: 'swing',queue: true});
    }
});
```

Comment: That's no different than [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) which simply combines `.mouseenter()` and `.mouseleave()` into one easy method.  In other words, `hover()` is shorthand for `.mouseenter().mouseleave()` so your code is really just the same as the OP's.

Comment: Didn't know `hover()` used `mouseenter()` and `mouseleave()` Thanks for your comment.